# exception in thread? New to netbeans.

Tags: netbeans

I am entering the space invaders code on netbeans from this website on my macbook pro and I cannot figure out this error. please help. I think it might have to do with my image location but im not sure.

http://zetcode.com/tutorials/javagamestutorial/spaceinvaders

the error says this when I try to run the program:

```
run:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(ImageIcon.java:217)
    at Board.gameInit(Board.java:58)
    at Board.<init>(Board.java:45)
    at SpaceInvaders.<init>(SpaceInvaders.java:8)
    at SpaceInvaders.main(SpaceInvaders.java:18)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 2 seconds)
```

thanks

Comment: Your real problem is:  at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(ImageIcon.java:217)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the image files which should be in the folder "spacepix" according to the code on the website. 
Since they cannot be found in your project path at the given location the nullpointer-exception is thrown.

Comment: Hey, so where should the spacepix folder and picture files be placed?